# Error to use autopulous-angular2-soap in Ionic 2

Tags: soap, ionic2

when i use autopulous-angular2-soap in Ionic 2, i get the error: "(void 0) is not a function"

I'm just install the pack, import in app.modules.ts and import xdom.js and xdom2jso.js in my app.html

Does anyone have an implementation example for me?

app.module.ts

```
...

import {SoapService} from "autopulous-angular2-soap/soap.service";

...

providers: [SoapService]
```

app.html

```
  <script src="../../node_modules/autopulous-angular2-soap/vendor/autopulous-xdom/xdom.js"></script>
  <script src="../../node_modules/autopulous-angular2-soap/vendor/autopulous-xdom2jso/xdom2jso.js"></script>
```

I also did a test putting the imports xdom and xdom2jso in the src/index.html

Answer (score 0):

***Below code is works fine for me***

**Input:**

```
let input = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
  <soap:Body> \
    <**WebMethodName** xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
      <_Param1_>test</_Param1_> \
      <_Param2_>test2</_Param2_> \
    </**WebMethodName** > \
  </soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>';
```

**Headers:**

```
this.headers = {
responseType: "text",
headers: new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8')};
```

**Http Call:**
*use http client*

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/yourwebservice.asmx', this.input, this.headers)
  .subscribe((response) => {
   let result = new DOMParser().parseFromString(res,"text/xml").getElementsByTagName("**WebMethodName**Result")[0].innerHTML;}, (error) => {\\Error Block });
```